# Asp.net multiple gridviews, checkboxes in headertemplate select all / deselect all functionality

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using two gridview controls in my aspx page. And I have a column of checkbox in both my controls. I am facilitating the user to select/deselect all checkboxes in my both gridviews by providing a checkbox in the header template of both gridviews and using java script functions. below is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UncheckParent(obj) {
        var isUnchecked = obj.checked;
        if (isUnchecked == false) {
            var frm = document.forms[0];
            for (i = 0; i < frm.length; i++) {
                if (frm.elements[i].id.indexOf('chkSelectAllCheckboxes') != -1) {
                    frm.elements[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    function CheckAll(obj) {
        var row = obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
        var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
                inputs[i].checked = obj.checked;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But the problem is that once i select or deselect one of such checkboxes all checkboxes in both the gridviews get checked. I can also give a short example of what is happening. Two gridviews gdvwStudents and gdvwTeachers. Both have checkbox column and a check box in header template. using above code when I click header checkbox of gdvwStudents, all checkboxes in gdvStudents and gdvTeachers get selected. Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed it:

```
        function UnCheckAllContainer(obj) {
        var isUnchecked = obj.checked;
        if (isUnchecked == false) {
            var frm = document.forms[0];
            for (i = 0; i < frm.length; i++) {
                if (frm.elements[i].id.indexOf('chkSelectAllCheckboxesContainers') != -1
                ) {
                    frm.elements[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function CheckAllContainer(chk) {
        $('#<%=gdvwContainers.ClientID %>').find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
            if (this != chk) {
                this.checked = chk.checked;
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You should be getting the check boxes inside the particular grid where the header is clicked; instead, you are getting `ALL` the checkboxes created on the form! That's incredibly inefficient and explains why everything is checked/unchecked regardless of which header you click.

If you can use jQuery, you should be able to rewrite those functions into something like this:

```
function checkAll(gridID,checkbox) {
    $("#"+gridID+" input:checkbox").attr("checked",checkbox.checked);
}
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99b9B/2/) for a quick example.

Answer (score 0):

Add the javascript function as per below

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function SelectAll(id, grd) {
     //get reference of GridView control
     var grid = null;
     if (grd = "1") {
         grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>");
     }
     else {
         grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridView2.ClientID %>");
     }


     //variable to contain the cell of the grid
     var cell;

     if (grid.rows.length > 0) {
         //loop starts from 1. rows[0] points to the header.
         for (i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
             //get the reference of first column
             cell = grid.rows[i].cells[0];

             //loop according to the number of childNodes in the cell
             for (j = 0; j < cell.childNodes.length; j++) {
                 //if childNode type is CheckBox                 
                 if (cell.childNodes[j].type == "checkbox") {
                     //assign the status of the Select All checkbox to the cell checkbox within the grid
                     cell.childNodes[j].checked = document.getElementById(id).checked;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
</script>
```

and handle Rowbound event of gridviews bind call of javascript function as per below

```
   protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        { 
            //Find the checkbox control in header and add an attribute
            ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("cbSelectAll")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:SelectAll('" + 
                    ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("cbSelectAll")).ClientID + "'" + ", '1')" );
        }
    }

    protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        { 
            //Find the checkbox control in header and add an attribute
            ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("cbSelectAll")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:SelectAll('" + 
                    ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("cbSelectAll")).ClientID + "'" + ", '2')" );
        }
    }
```